# Interfaces in practical example

Tags: c#, .net

I'm thinking about `Classified` ads application.

I want to gather all common properties for every article inside `abstract class` `ArticleBase` which is fine I think, but I have some doubt about `interface`.

Having this application in mind (classified ads) what would you put inside interface (something that every article must implement)?

thanks

Comment: Between abstract class and interface, it all depends up on your requirements, which would imply on what you are going to do with the Article object. You might get better directions if you post specific problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would create an interface `IArticle` which defines all the (common) properties every article should have.

Then you define the abstract class `ArticleBase` which implements the `IArticle` interface and contains the implementation of the properties and methods which will be the same for every article. This saves you creating the same implementation for every class that implements `IArticle`.

Lastly you inherit the abstract class with your specific `Classified` class and put the classified-specific code parts inside that class.

Comment: Because `ArticleBase` is not a complete implementation. It would only define the implementation of the common properties and functions, whereas the more specific parts are left to the class itself.